# Use document.getElementById for elements that load from server data

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura-iteration, lightning-renderer

I use `document.getElementById` with the `id` attribute to locate elements in my component. I cannot use `component.find` and `aura:id` because the elements are generated from an iteration.

This iteration is over a list of records that I get from the server.

**PROBLEM**

`document.getElementById` cannot find the elements because they are not rendered yet - they will be rendered only after the server returns the records.

**CURRENT SOLUTION**

I have put the `document.getElementById` inside the `aura:handler name="change"` event, and also then I use a waiting mechanism to check if the element exist:

**MARKUP**

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.records}" action="{!c.recordsFinishedLoading}"/>
<aura:attribute name="maxSelectionsTry" type="Integer" default="5" />

<aura:attribute name="records" type="sObject[]" description="list of records" />

<nav class="slds-context-bar__secondary" role="navigation">
    <ul class="slds-grid">  
        <li class="slds-context-bar__item">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-context-bar__label-action" title="labelAccount}" onclick="{!c.openAccount}">
                <span class="slds-truncate" title="labelAccount">labelAccount</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="slds-context-bar__item slds-context-bar__dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_hover">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-context-bar__label-action" title="labelRecords}" onclick="{!c.openRecords}">
                <span class="slds-truncate" title="labelRecords">labelRecords</span>
            </a>
            <div class="slds-context-bar__icon-action slds-p-left_none">
                <lightning:icon iconName="utility:chevrondown" size="x-small" alternativeText="Open Submenu"/>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-dropdown">
                <ul class="slds-dropdown__list" role="menu">

                    <aura:if isTrue="{! and(v.records, v.records.length>0)}">
                        <!--iterate on all records-->
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="record">
                            <li class="slds-dropdown__item" role="presentation">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="{!record.Id}" onclick="{!c.openRecordFromMenu}">
                                    <span class="slds-truncate" title="{!record.Name}">{!record.Name}</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </aura:if>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
recordsFinishedLoading: function(component, event, helper) {
    var recordId = "someHardCodedID";
    helper.findId(component, helper, recordId)
}
```

**HELPER**

```
findId: function(component, helper, recordId) {
    var itemById = document.getElementById(recordId);
    if (itemById) {
        // do some css stuff on this item
    }
    else {
        // element does not exist yet - so sleep and retry (for maxSelectionsTry times)
        var maxSelectionsTry = component.get("v.maxSelectionsTry");
        if (maxSelectionsTry > 0){
            component.set("v.maxSelectionsTry", maxSelectionsTry-1);
            setTimeout(function() {
                helper.findId(component, helper, grantId);
            }, 1000 /*1second*/);
        }
    }
},
```

I have tried to use `document.getElementById` from `aura:handler name="change"`  but it returns null.

I have tried to use `document.getElementById` from the custom `afterRender` but it returns null.

**QUESTION**

Is there any other way to wait for the page to load and then `document.getElementById` would work?

Is there a nicer way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Your premise is incorrect. You can find elements created by aura:iteration. You're just trying to get them too early in the life cycle. Also, your component code looks like it basically same straight from SLDS. You need to modify it appropriately or it won't work.

Comment: @sfdcfox my component works. I have added here only a portion of it . How can I get the elements later on the life cycle? I have tried with afterRender and it did not work

Comment: There's no convenient way to determine when they'll be available. I still think you're approaching this from the wrong direction. It'd be a lot easier to just bind whatever it is you're doing into part of the data structure.

Comment: @sfdcfox - as you have suggested - I have added the css selection to the returned server records (added a 'className' non-existing field in my JavaScript) and the whole process became much more simple - no need for `document.getElementById` anymore. Thanks. My question now is - what to do with this StackExchange question?

Comment: I'd recommend that you answer it, so people can learn from your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick answer:**  There is no way to decide when the elements are rendered already, and then to query and use `document.getElementById` - the way I posted in the question - to sleep in a loop, is an ugly, but working, way to do that.

I had a solution to my problem by the help of @sfdcfox, and what I did is - adding the css name to the records after they returned from server, while in the markup I am binding the className to it:

**MARKUP CHANGES:**

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="record">
    <li class="slds-dropdown__item" role="presentation">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" class="{!record.className}" id="{!record.Id}" onclick="{!c.openRecordFromMenu}">
            <span class="slds-truncate" title="{!record.Name}">{!record.Name}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</aura:iteration>
```

**CONTROLLER CHANGES IN THE METHOD**

```
getRecords: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.getRecords(component, helper);
},
```

**HELPER CHANGES IN THE METHOD** - mainly adding the `addSelectedRecordClass` method after data was received:

```
getRecords: function(component, helper){
    // get records from server - a list of sObjects
    var action = component.get("c.getRecords");
    action.setParams({
        sObjectName: 'Contact',
        commaDelimitedFieldNames: 'Id,Name'
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            var records = response.getReturnValue();
            records = helper.addSelectedRecordClass(component, records);
            component.set("v.records", records);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

// find the selected record in the given record list, and add a css class to highlight it
addSelectedRecordClass: function(component, records) {
    var selectedRecordId = component.get("v.selectedRecord");
    for(var i=0; i<records.length; i++) {
        if (records[i].Id == selectedRecordId)
            records[i].className = 'selectedMenuItem';
        else
            records[i].className = '';
    }
    return records;
},
```